# Multivariable Calculus question, show limit of equation DNE

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {3xy} {x^3+2y^2}$$ Does not exist.

This was on an old  test. I am not sure what to show since it's intuitively obvious that as $x$ and $y$ approaches $0$, the denominator will become $0$ and thus DNE.

Am I wrong to argue in words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator goes to zero too, so it may exist. But try to look at the case where $x=y=t$ and let $t$ go to zero.

A basic rule is, that the multiplicities of the zeroes in the numerator need to be strictly greater than the multiplicities of the denominator for having a continuous function.

Comment: The question asks to show that the limit DNE. According to the rule you mentioned, it means that the denominator will reach $0$ faster than numerator, so that the equation DNE as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$?

Comment: It is not an equation at all, it is a limit which doesn't exist. So simple said, the numerator doesn't get fast enough to zero.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}y=x&\;\;:\;\;\frac{3x^2}{x^3+2x^2}=\frac3{x+2}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac3{0+2}=\frac32\\
y=0&\;\;:\;\;\frac0{x^3}=0\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

[By Sequential Criterion of Limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limit_of_a_function_in_terms_of_sequences)
 : $(x_n,y_n)=({1\over n},{1\over n})\to (0,0)$ but  $f(x_n,y_n)\to {3\over 2}$ and $(p_n,q_n)=({1\over n},{2\over n})\to (0,0)$ but $f(p_n,q_n)\to {3\over 4}$ so limit does not exists!